# Can you programmatically look up a word in the Mac OS's built-in dictionary?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, dictionary

I'd like to have a program of mine retrieve a definition of a word. Is there a way to access the built-in dictionary using Objective-C? (i.e. the one that Dictionary.app and command-control-D use)

Answer (score 6):

You can take a look at Apple's [Dictionary Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/DictionaryServicesProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).